# How to delete the last item of a collection in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, collections

I made a program with python and mongodb to do some diaries. Like this

[image: slice diary]

Sometimes I want to delete the last sentence, just by typing "delete!"
But I dont know how to delete in a samrt way. I dont want to use "skip".
Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be it first or last item, `MongoDB` maintains unique `_id` key for each record and thus you can just pass that id field in your delete query either using `deleteOne()` or `deleteMany()`. Since only one record to delete you need to use `deleteOne()` like

```
db.collection_name.deleteOne({"_id": "1234"}) // replace 1234 with actual id
```

Comment: @john_zh, you can use `skip()` and `limit()`