# Find and delete last entered entry from MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I added an element I need to delete it from my mongodb collection. It's the last entry I've entered. I've been following this link: [How to delete the last item of a collection in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030332/how-to-delete-the-last-item-of-a-collection-in-mongodb). However, I'm not find to find the ID and I'm not able to extract this value from the Cursor (?). This is what I've done so far:

```
const db = client.db(databaseName);

let x = db
.collection("ford_twitter")
.find()
.sort({_id:-1});
```

The terminal log is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the last entry first check it's there using `find`. Once you find it, you can delete it.

I'll give you a complete example of how to achieve it:

```
async function find(){
try{
const call = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
result = await call.db("todos")
                   .collection("quotes")
                   .find({})
                   .sort("_id", -1).limit(1)
                   .toArray()
console.log(result)                   
} catch(e){console.log(e)}
}
find()
```

---

In MongoDB, there are a couple of new objects like Cursor. To get the standard objects you need to read how to use the Cursor: it has properties and methods...

`toArray()` will give an array of that one element, that you can inspect.

Comment: This gives me the following error: Error: Illegal sort clause, must be of the form [['field1', '(ascending|descending)'], ['field2', '(ascending|descending)']]

Comment: Gives me the following: ReferenceError: _id is not defined

Comment: Gives me: Promise { <pending> }

Comment: @cyruslk that's what the post should've included. try it & let me know